# Error para acceder a facebook con ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic3, facebook

Alguien me puede ayudar con este problema estoy intentando conectar a su `Facebook` del usuario con `Ionic 3`. Tengo este error

> Facebook error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: Error al
>   realizar la consulta. [extra]: null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo logre solucionar gerenado la clave hash
Descargue openssl-0.9.8e_X64 
y ejecute

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

lo agregue la clave a facebook developers y se soluciono el problema

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de los que tengan MAC a mi me funciono de la siguiente manera:

1. `cd /Users/<usuario>/.android/` =>  `cd /Users/saidllamas/.android/`
2. `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`
3. Introduzca la contraseña del almacén de claves:  `android`
4. Salida => XXXXXX+bNMXoaXXXXXInKfXXXXX=
5. [image: Colocar la cadena del paso anterior aquí]